# Redux State doesnt change in comonent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The reducers and actions are being called and working properly but my react components arent being changed after state is being changed.

This is my actions called cart.js:

```
import { ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_FROM_CART } from './types';

export const addToCart = item => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: ADD_TO_CART,
        payload: {
            item 
        }
    });
}

export const removeFromCart = uid => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: REMOVE_FROM_CART,
        payload: {
            uid 
        }
    });
}
```

This is my reducers file called cart.js:

```
import { ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_FROM_CART } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = [];

//Cannot mutate array in reducer 

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch(type){
        case ADD_TO_CART:
            for(var i = 0; i < state.length; i++){
                if(state[i].item.uid === payload.item.uid){
                    state[i].item.qty ++;
                    return [...state];
                }
            }
            return [...state, payload];
        case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
            for(var j = 0; j < state.length; j++){
                    if(state[j].item.uid === payload.uid){
                        state[j].item.qty = 1;
                    }
            }
            return state.filter(cartItem => cartItem.item.uid !== payload.uid);

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

My component files:
Cart.js:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { removeFromCart } from '../actions/cart';

import CartItem from './CartItem';

const Cart = ({ cart }) => {

    return (
        <div>
           <h1>Cart</h1>
           {cart.map(cartItem => (
               <div style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
                   <CartItem cartItem={cartItem.item} key={cartItem.item.uid} />
               </div>
           ))}
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    cart: state.cart
})

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { removeFromCart }
)(Cart);
```

CartItem.js:

```
import React from 'react'

import { removeFromCart } from '../actions/cart';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


const CartItem = ({ cartItem, removeFromCart }) => {

    const handleRemoveClick = () => {
        console.log('clicked', cartItem.uid);
        removeFromCart(cartItem.uid);
    }

    return (
        <div onClick={handleRemoveClick}>
            {cartItem.name}
            {cartItem.qty}
        </div>
    )
}

export default connect(
    null,
    { removeFromCart }
)(CartItem);
```

Im trying to learn redux using react and any help is appreciated. Are for loops allowed in reducers? Im not sure why it isnt updating, the redux devtools shows everything is working. Specifically the part that isnt working is the item quantity is not being updated in component. When i remove an item it works.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO ! It seems that you are mutating your state in your reducer wich is a bad idea : https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-mutate-state. You may also use useSelector hook instead of mapStateToProps (https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks). You should consider using https://redux-toolkit.js.org/ which comes with an immutable library : Immer (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#direct-state-mutation)

Comment: That helped! But not fully. The issue is where the increment of quantity comes in. How can i increment it without mutating it? I've tried newState = [...state], then the logic but doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Don't mutate the redux state in reducers. Copy the state and mutate it.

```
const newState = [...state];
//mutate newState;
return newState;
```

Comment: Ive tried this and it still wont let me increment qty in reducer. It still says im trying to mutate it even tho im not referencing state only newState.